# Retrieve bbc weather data with identical span class and nested spans

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull data form BBC weather with a view to use in a home automation dashboard.

The HTML code I can pull fine and I can pull one set of temps but it just pulls the first.

```html
</li>
<li class="daily__day-tab day-20150418 ">
<a data-ajax-href="/weather/en/2646504/daily/2015-04-18?day=3" href="/weather/2646504?day=3" rel="nofollow">
<div class="daily__day-header">
<h3 class="daily__day-date">
<span aria-label="Saturday" class="day-name">Sat</span>
</h3>
</div>
<span class="weather-type-image weather-type-image-40" title="Sunny"><img alt="Sunny" src="http://static.bbci.co.uk/weather/0.5.327/images/icons/tab_sprites/40px/1.png"/></span>
<span class="max-temp max-temp-value"> <span class="units-values temperature-units-values"><span class="units-value temperature-value temperature-value-unit-c" data-unit="c">13<span class="unit">°C</span></span><span class="unit-types-separator"> </span><span class="units-value temperature-value temperature-value-unit-f" data-unit="f">55<span class="unit">°F</span></span></span></span>
<span class="min-temp min-temp-value"> <span class="units-values temperature-units-values"><span class="units-value temperature-value temperature-value-unit-c" data-unit="c">5<span class="unit">°C</span></span><span class="unit-types-separator"> </span><span class="units-value temperature-value temperature-value-unit-f" data-unit="f">41<span class="unit">°F</span></span></span></span>
<span class="wind wind-speed windrose-icon windrose-icon--average windrose-icon-40 windrose-icon-40--average wind-direction-ene" data-tooltip-kph="31 km/h, East North Easterly" data-tooltip-mph="19 mph, East North Easterly" title="19 mph, East North Easterly">
<span class="speed"> <span class="wind-speed__description wind-speed__description--average">Wind Speed</span>
<span class="units-values windspeed-units-values"><span class="units-value windspeed-value windspeed-value-unit-kph" data-unit="kph">31 <span class="unit">km/h</span></span><span class="unit-types-separator"> </span><span class="units-value windspeed-value windspeed-value-unit-mph" data-unit="mph">19 <span class="unit">mph</span></span></span></span>
<span class="description blq-hide">East North Easterly</span>
</span>
```

This is my code which isn’t working

```
import urllib2
import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmlFile=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2646504?day=1')
htmlData = htmlFile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlData)

table=soup.find("div","daily-window")
temperatures=[str(tem.contents[0]) for tem in table.find_all("span",class_="units-value temperature-value temperature-value-unit-c")]
mintemp=[str(min.contents[0]) for min in table.find_("span",class_="min-temp min-temp-value")]
maxtemp=[str(min.contents[0]) for min in table.find_all("span",class_="max-temp max-temp-value")]
windspeeds=[str(speed.contents[0]) for speed in table.find_all("span",class_="units-value windspeed-value windspeed-value-unit-mph")]


pprint.pprint(zip(temperatures,temp2,windspeeds))
```

Answer (score 0):

your min and max temp extract is wrong.You just find the hole min temp span (include both c and f format).Get the first thing of content gives you empty string.

And the min temp tag identify `class=min-temp.min-temp-value` is not the same with the c-type min temp `class=temperature-value-unit-c`.So I suggest you to use `css` selector.

Eg,find all of your min temp span could be

```
table.select('span.min-temp.min-temp-value span.temperature-value-unit-c')
```

This means select all `class=temperature-value-unit-c` spans which are children of `class=min-temp min-temp-value` spans.

So do the other information lists like `max_temp` `wind`